# How can I see someone's accept rate?

Tags: support

Where is the % accept rate in Game Development, which normally appears under a question-writer's badges in other Stack Exchange sites such as Stack Overflow?

I've seen it mentioned in Game Development.meta posts, and can't find anything suggesting it's no longer used. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does still appear under a askers badge on the question page. I don't know the exact conditions that need to be met, but it will not show up for users that haven't asked a question before and haven't had a question open for long enough.

For example, a user that has asked questions in the past and is asking a new question:

[image]

Will show an accept rate below their badge.

EDIT

---

Found the rules in the [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

> The following rules are used in the calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined
>     by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Comment: Please could you provide a link to a question with an accept rate? I can't see them on gamedev or gamedev meta, even on questions asked by people who asked questions before, by you, or by users with gold badges, including questions asked over two years ago such as this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47425/unity3d-collider-performances-on-mobile-ios-devices) currently shows an accept rate of 75%.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that too. I wonder what the rule is for whether it's shown or not (it can't *just* be those in this answer, for the reasons in my above comment).

Comment: Maybe it's only shown for people who have failed to accept an answer in a certain number of days, and then it goes away again if they then accept answers? One way to find out... :-)

Comment: @MikeHoward I've updated with the rules for showing the accept rate.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find that, even searching the blog for "accept rate". I guess a lower proportion of users from gamedev have answered four eligible questions, because it's much less busy than stack overflow. Maybe four is too high for this site?